# How can I hide/show a div-container in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typescript, toggle

I'm trying to use the `toggleClass` method for hiding/showing a div-container by clicking a button. Therefore I use jQuery. It works when the class `.hide` is set to `visibility: hidden`.

However I want to make the div container `.aufklapp-container` visible when I'm clicking the button. For CSS I tried this:

```
.table { visibility: hidden } 
.hide { visibility: visible }
```

However the div-container doesn't change to visible. It stays hidden. Help me please, I don't get it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".aufklapp-button").click(function() {
    $(".aufklapp-container").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.aufklapp-button {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: #7F868D;
  padding: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 30px 20px 40px;
  border-color: #8D0011;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.table td {
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
}

.table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
}

.hide {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-button">
  <input class="aufklapp-button" type="button" value="Platzhalter für Kategorie"></input>
  <div class="aufklapp-container">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Zielerreichung in %</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 1</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 2</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 3</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 4</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you've set `visibility: hidden` on the `table` element, not the parent `.aufklapp-container`, therefore toggling the class there does nothing. If you move the `visibility` property to the correct class in your CSS, the code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".aufklapp-button").click(function() {
    $(".aufklapp-container").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.aufklapp-button {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: #7F868D;
  padding: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aufklapp-container {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.table {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 30px 20px 40px;
  border-color: #8D0011;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.table td {
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
}

.table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
}

.hide {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-button">
  <input class="aufklapp-button" type="button" value="Platzhalter für Kategorie" />
  <div class="aufklapp-container">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Zielerreichung in %</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 1</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 2</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 3</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kriterium 4</td>
          <td>Regler</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, just as an aside, it would make more sense to rename the `hide` class to `show`, as that better matches its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative besides the one given before would be change the code a little bit, changing the JavaScript code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aufklapp = $(".aufklapp-container");
  $(".aufklapp-button").click(function() {
    aufklapp.attr("hidden", aufklapp.attr('hidden') ? null : true);
  });
});
```

and adding the hidden attribute to the HTML element as `<div class="aufklapp-container" hidden>` and for the last on your CSS, remove the `.hide` class and the `visibility: hidden;` property from your `.table` class.

```
.table {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 30px 20px 40px;
  border-color: #8D0011;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.table td {
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
}

.table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 45%;
}
```

This will give you 3 benefits to your code: (1) a better accessibility using the hidden attribute on the markup (you can use it with others [ARIA attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) if is needed); (2) you cache your container through a reference, avoiding fetching it using the jQuery code `$(".aufklapp-container")` in every click; and (3) is one less CSS generic class in your codebase.